# is cloudflare now using let's encrypt certificates for edge?

Tags: lets-encrypt, cloudflare

i just added a new domain to cloudflare and the edge certificate is let's encrypt r3, shown in control panel and by inspecting in browser when on the domain's website.

my existing domains still have the regular 1-yr certs. wonder if they'll switch to let's encrypt after expiration.

anyone else noticed?

Comment: Really? What date was the certificate issued?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Yes](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/ssl-tls/certificate-authorities).

> ### Certificate authorities
>
> Cloudflare may issue certificates for SSL products from any of the
> following Certificate Authorities (CAs):
>
> - DigiCert
> - GlobalSign
> - Let’s Encrypt
> - Sectigo (formerly Comodo)

I also found this recent [Cloudflare community post](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cloudflare-using-letsencrypt-cert/282083):

> [michael](https://community.cloudflare.com/u/michael) MVP '20 - '21 
> 3d
>
> Cloudflare use multiple certificate authorities, including Let’s
> Encrypt. These certs are independent of any certs on your origin,
> which you should continue to maintain with your acme.sh script.
> [domjh](https://community.cloudflare.com/u/domjh) liked this

There is a [blog post from March 27, 2021](https://blog.cloudflare.com/advanced-certificate-manager/) explaining one way to get a cert signed by LE or Digicert:

> ### Introducing: Advanced Certificate Manager
>
> #### Additional Features
>
> Apart from the security features that ACM has to offer, we are excited
> to give our customers an easy-to-use and configurable certificate
> management solution. With ACM, customers will now be able to issue up
> to 100 edge certificates per zone, which includes the zone apex and up
> to 50 hostnames. This means your certificate now has multi-level
> support, so you can create certificates for second and third-level
> hostnames. **In addition, customers will be able to choose their
> preferred validation method (HTTP, TXT, or Email) and their
> certificate authority (Let’s Encrypt or Digicert).**

There is probably more in their docs that I didn't find.